# How to write Keyboard notifications in Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsnotificationcenter, swift4.2

I'm trying to update this code from Swift 3 to Swift 4.2

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil);
```

So far, I've just tried the auto corrections given by the compiler. This results in code like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: .UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil);
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't take me far, resulting in additional error:
"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Has anyone solved this please?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just replace `.UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification` with `UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification` and it will solve your problem.

And final code will be:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```